# LLDB fails to read the memory adresses in the argv pointer-array, given as an argument in the main method in C

Tags: c, lldb

I am trying to reproduce an example given in the book "The Art of Exploitation" by Jon Erickson. The procedure is actually pretty simple: I want to give commandline-arguments to my program and examine their memory addresses using lldb.
The C class looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int arg_count, char *arg_list[]) {
   // something
}
```

To examine the program with lldb i do the following:

```
lldb ./a.out
(lldb) target create "./a.out"
Current executable set to '/Users/<path>/a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`main + 22 at commandline.c:7:50, address = 0x0000000100003f06
(lldb) run first second

Process 4161 launched: '/Users/<path>/a.out' (x86_64)
Process 4161 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003f06 a.out`main(arg_count=3, arg_list=0x00007ffeefbffa40) at commandline.c:7:50
Target 0: (a.out) stopped.
```

So now I expect the next three memory-words, after the address stored in arg_list, to point to the adresses of the strings given through the command line. I know that the first argument is always a string that contains the path to my ./a.out file.

```
(lldb) x/3xw arg_list
0x7ffeefbffa40: 0xefbffbb8 0x00007ffe 0xefbffbe9
(lldb) x/s 0xefbffbb8
error: failed to read memory from 0xefbffbb8.
(lldb) x/s 0x00007ffe
error: failed to read memory from 0x7ffe.
```

So when I try to examine the memory, it always fails. Does anyone know why? The example in the book uses the gdb debugger and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book looks to be written for 32-bit code, but your system is 64-bit.  So the pointers are 64 bits each.  Try `x/3xg arg_list`, where the `g` is for "giant", gdb's size letter for an 8-byte object.  This should give you three 64-bit values starting with `0x00007ffeefbffbb8` and then you can `x/s 0x00007ffeefbffbb8`.

(You may want to find a different book that matches your system better, or set up a 32-bit Linux VM for following along with it.)

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to follow along as good as I can. The low-level stuff is new to me. Do you have any book recommendations on this topic?

Comment: @P-Balk: Not offhand, sorry.